# How to represent the floor function using mathematical notation?

Tags: functions, notation, definition

I'm curious as to how the floor function can be defined using mathematical notation.

What I mean by this, is, instead of a word-based explanation (i.e. "The closest integer that is not greater than x"), I'm curious to see the mathematical equivalent of the definition, if that is even possible.

For example, a word-based explanation of the factorial function would be "multiply the number by all integers below it", whereas a mathematical equivalent of the definition would be $n! = \prod^n_{i=1}i$.

**So, in summary: how can I show what $\lfloor x \rfloor$ means without words?**

Comment: "instead of a word-based explanation" - it can happen that insisting on formal notation often hurts clarity more than helping it. In this case, since the textual definition is straightforward, why bother?

Comment: For curiosity's sake; consider it a puzzle

Comment: What do you mean by that big capital pi with all those other symbols around it?  Can you describe that "without words" please?  In your accepted answer, what does arctan mean?  My point is, all notation was invented to describe some intellectual phenomenon, which may in turn have been based on some earlier idea, etc. until the whole thing ultimately boils down to cavemen telling how many mastadon had been successfully hunted by holding up fingers.

Comment: @cobaltduck "hire or otherwise persuade a caveman to walk clockwise a circle of radius 0.5/pi until he has covered a distance of x. then have him walk counter-clockwise back to his starting point and subtract from x the distance he walked back" it helps to mark the starting point with a mastodon. ;p

Comment: see alsso: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1810859/51028

Answer (score 85, accepted):

For a real number $x$,
$$\lfloor x\rfloor=\max\{n\in\mathbb{Z}\mid n\leq x\}.$$
I'd like to add though, that "$\lfloor x\rfloor$" is mathematical notation, just as much as the right side of the above equation is; the right side might use more "basic" constructions, but you can then ask about
$$\max,\qquad\in,\qquad \mathbb{Z},\qquad {}\mathbin{\mid}{},\qquad \leq$$ 
and so on. At some point you just have to start writing notation and explaining it in words and hope your readers understand. So I disagree with your phrasing of the question.

Comment: I've always thought floor/ceiling to be basic themselves, so I suppose "basic" is in the eye of the beholder. (+1, of course.)

Comment: that's one step closer to the set-theoretic definition.

Comment: With the note that the $\max$ is well-defined because the set is bounded from above (by $x$), and every set of integers bounded above has a maximum element by the well-ordering principle.

Answer (score 31):

$\lfloor x \rfloor = x - \arctan(\tan(\pi x))/\pi$ ?...

Comment: Almost, [$\displaystyle\lfloor x \rfloor = (x - 0.5) - \frac{arctan(tan(\pi (x-0.5)))}{\pi}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x-0.5%29+-+%5Carctan%28%5Ctan%28%5Cpi+%28x-0.5%29%29%29%2F%5Cpi+%2C+%5Clfloor+x+%5Crfloor)

Comment: love this answer - so cool! i don't know why this one isn't accepted or voted higher, the rest are simply saying in notation what the question said in english so chickening out. this one computes it directly like a boss. also @gangqinlaohu

Comment: @agksmehx: Zev's answer should be the accepted one - no chickening out there, just the plain professional definition. (Of course this answer is a nice idea, too.)

Comment: One tiny quibble is that $\arctan$ is a multi-valued function, and this relies on taking the principal value, otherwise the answer could be any integer. It's somewhat similar to defining $|x|$ as $\sqrt{x^2}$, which could technically be $|x|$ or $-|x|$.

Comment: I like this answer because it's easy for me to see it implemented as a function in most curly-brace programming languages (e.g., C++, Java). It's unclear to me how Zev's answer could be coded in these languages. Now a language that is tailored for mathematical notation (e.g., Haskell) might be different, so I guess it depends on your perspective.

Comment: @Clayton: But which answer is clearer as to what $\lfloor x\rfloor$ **means** (which is usually the goal for things intended to be read by humans)? Besides, a computer seems far more likely to make round-off errors or mistakes trying to *mimick* $\pi$, an arbitrary real number $x$, subtraction, division, and the functions $\tan$ and $\arctan$, than in trying to compare numbers with $\leq$ (though I don't know anything about programming languages, so maybe I'm wrong about that).

Comment: @ZevChonoles right on on all points. The best approach is to build a programming language that allows the mathematical notation you wrote, and then 'code' it that way. I'm pretty sure Haskell supports that, or something close to it.

Comment: @HendrikVogt on re-reading the question there is some ambiguity so i sympathize with the other answers. the question is clear that "instead of words ..." paragraph is looking for more than a set notation replacement of english. on the other hand the next paragraph defines the factorial pretty much using mathematicalized english. i think that is just because the author wasn't aware of the cool gamma function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function which also directly computes the factorial.

Comment: @ClaytonStanley for programming the time complexity of the two answers is different. the set-notation requires a search which i would implement as start from 1, keep doubling until exceeds n, then do a binary search between the last two points. it is `O(log N)`. this answer is `O(1)`. the art, rather than science, of computer programming requires a human to understand and come up with a better algorithm. that is for a well-coded computer. for a human unacquainted with binary search computing or coding computing the set-theoretic answer can be difficult *in general*.

Comment: @ZevChonoles sorry to bust your answer; there is some ambiguity in the question so i sympathize. see response on computability above. round-off and mimicking pi tend to be second-order concerns in that there are well-defined way to get arbitrarily close to what you want. this answer seems particularly sensitive to roundoff concerns but a smart compiler would "see through" the `arctan(tan(..))`. the correct implementation could simply knock off bits rather than using your answer or this one. but being a math forum i would ignore computability issues unless that is the primary goal.

Comment: to the original author and everybody pitching in, i will interpret this answer in words: "walk clockwise a circle of radius `0.5/pi` until you have covered a distance of `x`. then walk counter-clockwise back to your starting point and subtract from `x` the distance you walked back :-)

Comment: But there is a problem, should you use the function with an integer, the result would be its preceding integer. I.e., `f(x) = (x - 0.5) - atan(tan(pi*(x - 0.5)))/pi`, `f(1) = 0`.

Comment: @agks, Wolter has this nice point...

Comment: *Ahem* This sort of mistake is less likely when writing things that convey meaning, as opposed to things that happen to give the correct answer...

Comment: @ZevChonoles i made the same mistake when writing it out in a way that conveys meaning by not adding the clause "unless you are already at the starting point". what you probably mean is that any time you give a method for arriving at the answer rather than just defining the answer there is an increased likelihood of making a mistake. that's just because there are more moving parts when you are describing how to arrive at an answer rather than just giving a definition or a test for the answer. right? i thought this was a useful debate in that it pinpointed the difference in the types of answers

Comment: @J.M. there was already a mistake in the answer, it was corrected in a comment, and there is one more flaw which can easily be rectified: subtract the value only if it is strictly less than one. there are probably other details if you wanted to actually implement it. but the point is that one type of answer (Zev's) defines the notation or declares properties of the answer. the other gives a reasonably efficient method to get the answer. this `arctan` answer answers a slightly different question: "how to efficiently compute the answer" (not in a programming sense but mathematically)

Comment: @J.M. similarly Zev's answer answers a slightly different question: "how to express the floor operator using more elementary ones" and he gave a great answer to that.

Comment: ultimately the question is ambiguous, but in being so it enlightened me tremendously in understanding the difference between declarative versus computable answers. there is more interesting stuff about how `tan` is itself computed versus how do you find the max of a bounded set. ultimately they have the same efficient solution and there are similarities between the efficient methods to arrive at an answer that i didn't think existed before. so, KUDOS+thank-you to @ZevChonoles and community for not closing or discouraging the question and letting it educate at least me! cheers :)

Comment: @Nathaniel: Why do you say that $\arctan$ is multi-valued? Isn't it widely accepted that it's the inverse function of $\tan\colon(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2)\to\mathbb R$? (For me as a mathematician this is the standard definition, and I don't know any programming language that would use another definition.)

Comment: @agksmehx: Still, the factorial should be _defined_ as a (finite) product, not via the Gamma function!

Comment: @Clayton and agksmehx: Using this as an _implementation_ for the floor function would be ludicrous (pardon my French). I'm pretty sure that any implementation of $\tan$ involves the floor function in some way of another.

Comment: @HendrikVogt $\tan(\theta + 2\pi n) = \tan(\theta)$ for any $n\in \mathbb{Z}$. Taking the $(-\pi,\pi]$ branch (or the $[0,2\pi)$ one) of the inverse function is just a matter of convention. Of course you're right that a computer language will only return a single value, but I didn't interpret the question as asking for an implementation so much as a formal expression.

Comment: @Nathaniel: We're talking about the $(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2)$ branch (the tangent is $\pi$-periodic) `:-)` Of course it's only convention, but it's the standard mathematical convention to use this branch and not another one.

Comment: @HendrikVogt d'oh, $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ is right of course. The point is just that this means we're defining $\lfloor x \rfloor$ in terms of a convention, rather than in terms of a really "fundamental" property of $\tanh$. I did say it was only a tiny quibble...

Comment: @Nathaniel what about my interpretation of `arctan(tan(θ))` as walking around in a circle `θ` and then measuring how far you are from the starting point? (to be precise either of two "poles" marked on the circle) it is a pretty fundamental concept encountered in real life, and therefore a solid rationale for using the principal value.

Comment: @HendrikVogt i agree factorial should be defined as a finite product. on that note for computing stirling and other approximations are also interesting.

Comment: @DVD how was this derived?

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Periodicity of tangent function and common sense?

Comment: see also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1810859/51028

Answer (score 20):

I am an engineer, perhaps this helps if you do not expect too much.

$x-(x$ mod $1$)

Comment: Follow-up: "How to represent $\bmod$ using mathematical notation?"

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - @J.M. I suppose it is very subjective, but I'd consider modulo to be a much simpler concept than the concepts that other answers are using

Comment: This is a notation that I think most mathematicians would not consider standard...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Yes, it is not a mathematical notation but it is a notation without words.

Comment: @newzad: The notation $\lfloor x\rfloor$ also has no words, and is much more widely accepted by mathematicians.

Comment: I would apply mod to the whole expression which would yield zero ...

Comment: @DominicMichaelis you are right, now I edit.

Comment: did nobody notice the directly computable answer below? ⌊x⌋=(x−0.5)−arctan(tan(π(x−0.5)))π

Comment: @agks, it also has not a few removable singularities...

Comment: @J.M. the singularities help solve the problem. here is the interpretation of the notation: "walk clockwise a circle of radius 0.5/pi until you have covered a distance of x. then walk counter-clockwise back to your starting point and subtract from x the distance you walked back" (no singularities; just a bit of centrifugal force if you're in a hurry ;p )

Comment: This is just a feedback loop of math implementations, since the most common modulo operator requires the use of the floor function, which is here represented using modulo... see the issue?

Answer (score 13):

Recursive way: $\lfloor x\rfloor \equiv \begin{cases}
1+\lfloor x-1\rfloor& x\ge1 \\
-1+\lfloor x+1\rfloor& x<-1 \\ 
0&0\le x<1\\
-1&-1\le x<0
\end{cases}$

Also directly(sort of) computes the answer.

Answer (score 9):

$\lfloor x\rfloor=n\leftrightarrow \{n\}=\{y\in\mathbb{Z}:\forall z\in\mathbb{Z}~ z\le x \rightarrow z\le y\}$

This game is fun!  Now let's prove 1+1=2.

Comment: The right side can be radically simplified to just: $\{n\} = \{y \in \mathbb{Z} : x \leq y\}$ ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You have raised a most-interesting question which has a beautiful solution.

The floor-function is characterized by the following formula,

$\boxed{
\;\; \forall n \in \mathbb{Z},x \in \mathbb{R} :: n \leq \lfloor x \rfloor \equiv n \leq x \;\;
}$

Indeed this states that ``$\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the greatest integer that is at-most $x$'':

1. $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is an ingeter at-most $x$ ---ie $x \leq \lfloor x \rfloor$.
   We obtain this my taking $n = \lfloor x \rfloor$ in the above formula.
2. It is also the largest such integer : 
   $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z},x \in \mathbb{R} :: n \leq x \implies n \leq \lfloor x \rfloor$. We obtain this from the characterization by weakening the equivalence $\equiv$ into an implication $\implies$.

Some immediate results from the characterization, for $n \in \mathbb{Z}, x \in \mathbb{R}$, are

1. $\lfloor x \rfloor < n \equiv x < n$, by negating the equivalence.
2. $\lfloor x \rfloor \leq x$, by taking $n = \lfloor x \rfloor$. [Contracting]
3. $\lfloor x \rfloor \leq \lfloor y \rfloor \Leftarrow x \leq y$, proven by the characterization and properties of $\leq$. [Order preserving]
4. $\lfloor \lfloor x \rfloor \rfloor = \lfloor x \rfloor$, characterization again. [Idempotent]

Other nifty theorems can be easily proven from this characterization, such as

1. $n = \lfloor x \rfloor \, \equiv \, ( n \leq x \text{ and } x<n+1)$
2. $\lfloor x+n \rfloor = \lfloor x \rfloor + n$
3. $\lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor y \rfloor \leq \lfloor x+y \rfloor $
4. $0\leq x \implies \lfloor \sqrt{\lfloor x \rfloor} \rfloor = \lfloor \sqrt{x} \rfloor$

Unlike the other answers presented earlier, this characterization shows its power in reasoning. For example, try proving one of the above theorems using one of the definitions presented by the others and then compare that with a proof using the characterization presented here.

These theorems and the characterization are explored in Feijen's ``The Joy of Formula Manipulation'', http://www.mathmeth.com/wf/files/wf2xx/wf268t.pdf.

Best regards,

Moses

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that this question can be better articulated as: *how can we compute the floor of a given number using real number field operations, rather than by exploiting the printed notation, which separates the real and fractional part, making nearby integers instantly identifiable.*

How about as Fourier series? If we subtract the function $y = x$ from $\lfloor x\rfloor$ then we get a periodic [sawtooth wave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave). Hey look, that Wikipedia page even mentions this relationship.

So if you obtain the Fourier series (a sum of sinusoidal functions of various frequencies and amplitudes) for the sawtooth wave $\lfloor x\rfloor - x$ and add $x$, then you have an approximation for $\lfloor x\rfloor$ which is as good to whatever accuracy you care to apply in evaluating the series. Obtaining the Fourier series for $\lfloor x\rfloor - x$  is a basically a matter of scaling the function to fit: finding the parameters to substitute into the generic equation to produce the right amplitude, frequency and offset.

But another answer is that the printed notation which approximates a number is computable. When a computer evaluates `floor(x)`, it's all math. The printed (or electronically stored) notation for a rational number which approximates a real number is a mathematical object.

Answer (score 3):

$$\lfloor x \rfloor = \text{supremum} \{n \in \mathbb{Z} : n \leq x\}$$

For a subset $S \subset X$, where we have an order $\leq$ on $X$, a supremum or least upper bound of $S$ is an element $M \in X$ such that
$$x \leq M, \,\,\,\,\, \forall x \in S$$
and for any $m \in X$ such that $x \leq m$ for all $x \in S$, we have $M \leq m$.

Comment: Can "max" then be put into mathematical notation as well? Or is this as mathematical as it can get?

Comment: @Sim You can make it more and more "formal" as you want. But it is useless beyond a point.

Comment: I first read this as "supermum"

Comment: @Sim $x = \sup(S) \iff \forall_{y\in U(S)}\left(x \leq y\right) \land x\in U(S)$, $U(S) = \left\{x \mid \forall_{y\in S} \left(y \leq x\right)\right\}$.

Answer (score 3):

There exists exactly one integer $n$ such that $n \le x < n+1$. We define $\lfloor x \rfloor$ to be this $n$.

Or, if you *really* like symbols: $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \ \exists! n \in \mathbb{Z} \ n \le x < n+1 \quad \lfloor x \rfloor := n$.

Answer (score 2):

$\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor = a \in \mathbb{Z}, a \le x \ni a\ge b \;\forall \;b \in \mathbb{Z}, b\le x$

Answer (score 1):

Another expression is
\begin{equation}
\lfloor x \rfloor = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (\sum_{k=-n}^n \mu(x-k)) - n - 1 \ ,
\end{equation}
where $\mu$ is the step function. The function $\mu$ has the expression
\begin{equation}
\mu(x) = \lim_{n  \rightarrow \infty} f(nx) \ ,
\end{equation}
where $f(x) = e^{-x^2} + \frac{2}{\pi} \textrm{Si}(x)$. We have
\begin{eqnarray}
f(x) & = & 1 + \frac{2}{\pi}x + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{\prod_{j=1}^k j} x^{2k} + \frac{2}{\pi} \frac{(\prod_{j=1}^{2k} j) (-1)^k}{(\prod_{j=1}^{2k+1} j)^2} x^{2k+1} .
\end{eqnarray}
The Taylor series converges for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Hence there is a representation for $\lfloor x \rfloor$ that applies multiplication, addition and limit.

Comment: Im not convinced. For starter the term exp(-x^2) can be omitted i think. Because exp( - n x^2) Goes to 0 as n Goes to +oo ...

Answer (score 0):

$$\large
\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor
=
\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}n\Theta\left(x - n\right)
\Theta\left(n + 1 - x\right)\,,
\qquad
x \not\in {\mathbb Z}
$$

$$\large
\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor
=
\lim_{z \to x^{+}}\left\lfloor z\right\rfloor\,,
\qquad
x \in {\mathbb Z}
$$